# Hamburger Menu removed on larger screen sizes

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive, hamburger-menu

i've created a hamburger menu for my website and i want it to disappear completely at larger screen sizes.I want to remove the class of .show  on all my nav elements at larger screen sizes.When I go at larger screen sizes my hamburger menu remains open.I don't know if the solution to this problem is simple but I am a bigginer at js and I don't know how to solve it. [small hamburger menu[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LkzT.png)

```js
// Select DOM Items
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-btn');
const menu = document.querySelector('.nav-menu');
const menuNav = document.querySelector('.nav-ul');
const navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item');

// Seti Initial State Of Menu
 let showMenu = false;  

menuBtn.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);

function toggleMenu() {
    if(!showMenu) {
menuBtn.classList.add('close');
menu.classList.add('show');
menuNav.classList.add('show');
navItems.forEach(item => item.classList.add('show'));


// Set menu state
showMenu = true;
    } else {
        menuBtn.classList.remove('close');
        menu.classList.remove('show');
        menuNav.classList.remove('show');
        navItems.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('show'));
        
        // Set Menu State
        showMenu = false;
    }
}
```

```css
.nav-logo-wrapper {
  .menu-btn {
    position: absolute;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    right: 35px;
    top: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    @include easeOut;

    .btn-line {
      width: 28px;
      height: 3px;
      margin: 0 0 5px 0;
      background: white;
      @include easeOut;
    }
    //   Rotate Into X With Menu Lines
    &.close {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
      transform: translate(180deg);

      .btn-line {
        // Line 1 - Rotate
        &:nth-child(1) {
          transform: rotate(45deg) translate(5px, 5px);
        }
        // Line 2 - Hide
        &:nth-child(2) {
          opacity: 0;
        }
        // Line 3 - Rotate

        &:nth-child(3) {
          transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(6.5px, -6.5px);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- navigation mobile menu -->
    <nav class="nav-menu animate__animated animate__fadeInRight">
        <ul class="nav-ul">
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link  current" href="index.html">
                Home
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link"  href="products.html">
        Products
            </a>
        </li>
         <li  class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link" href="#features">
                 About us
             </a>
         </li>
         
         <li  class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">
        Pricing
         </a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: please fix your snippet. It is actually returning an error.

Comment: mainly i'm interested in removing the .show class on larger screen sizes and I don't know how to modify the js to do that.

Comment: @dickdastardly The code provided by you does not work. Also, add the compiled `CSS` and not the uncompiled `SCSS`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using CSS media queries for this instead of JavaScript?

```css
.small {
  display: block;
}
.large {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen 
and (min-width : 500px)  {
  .small {
    display: none;
  }
  .large {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="small">Small/medium browser width only</div>
<div class="large">Larger browser width only</div>
```

Here's a great article on the subject: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/